# encode web url image in base64 in JS

Tags: javascript, image, url, download, base64

I am trying to load zip file from html page to pc hdd but was failing by now , to save there an image it should be encoded in base64 how it is possible to do the think if it is a web url image.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

    </script>
<img id = "myImage" src="http://files.smashingmagazine.com/wallpapers/feb-18/love-work/cal/feb-18-love-work-cal-320x480.png">
<input type = 'button' onclick="func()" value = "press me">
<script >
    function getBase64Image(img){
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.width = img.width;
        canvas.height = img.height;
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
        var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        return dataUrl.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/,"")
    }





    function func() {


var image = document.querySelector("#myImage");
var base64 = getBase64Image(image);

alert(base64);


}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you may need to unzip it before encoding

Comment: I have no zip I will create it when get base64 encoding of the image

Comment: So, you need a way to turn a image URL to base64, and then zip it, which the page can then download. Did i get that right?

Comment: Yes I am going to use jszip to download it afterward zip.file("hello.png", base64, {base64:true});
alert(base64);
zip.generateAsync({type:"base64"}).then(function(blob) {
   location.href="data:application/zip;base64,"+blob;
});

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it by using httprequest object to load the file.

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.withCredentials = true;
req.open("GET", sFileUrl, false); // 'false': synchronous.
req.send(null);
//return req.response;
```

if you need base64, you can convert the byte array to base64.

```
var u8 = new Uint8Array(req.response);
var b64encoded = btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, u8));
return b64encoded;
```

make sure you can access the URL image.
Hope it helps.